# Various ways to return multiple values of the same type

Tags: java

Say I have a Java method that prompts the user for various `double` values and returns them back to the main method:

```
  double Prompt(double theta, double omega, double length, double mass) {
    double theta_read, omega_read, length_read, mass_read;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Initial angle [rad]: ");
    theta_read = 0.0;
    try {
      theta_read = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println(ioe);
      System.exit(1);
    }
    theta = theta_read;
    System.out.print("Initial angular velocity [rad/sec]: ");
    omega_read = 0.0;
    try {
      omega_read = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println(ioe);
      System.exit(1);
    }
    omega = omega_read;
    System.out.print("Length of pendulum [m]: ");
    length_read = 0.0;
    try {
      length_read = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println(ioe);
      System.exit(1);
    }
    length = length_read;
    System.out.print("Mass of pendulum bob [kg]: ");
    mass_read = 0.0;
    try {
      mass_read = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println(ioe);
      System.exit(1);
    }
    mass = mass_read;
    //return code here
  }
```

Using the example above, what are the different ways one could return multiple values of the same type, and what are the merits of each?

Comment: Your code is a little weird because the doubles you're passing in are passed by value. Changing their values in that method will not change the values of the ones in the calling code - maybe you knew that. Anyway, it's redundant and unnecessary to have a *_read version of every variable in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to return multiple values is by returning a Double array, arrayList, or any type-double hashMap.

If you have to return three values, using arrays would be:

```
double array[] = new double[3];
array[0] = value1;
array[1] = value2;
array[2] = value3;
return array;
```

The problem of using this solution is that you must need to know the quantity of values you need to return from the beginning. If that's not the case you should proceed with the next one:
And with arraylists

```
ArrayList<double> arraylist = new ArrayList<double>();
arraylist.add(value1);
arraylist.add(value2);
arraylist.add(value3);
return arraylist;
```

This solution can be better for cases where you don't have the quantity of elements to use. And, if you want to use string-indexed values, you can use Hashmaps:

```
HashMap<String, double> map = new HashMap<String, double>();
map.put("first value", value1);
map.put("second value", value2);
map.put("third value", value3);
return map;
```

In all situations you can do this inside a for-loop (obviously), however, depending on the situation, if you have a limited quantity of elements, using simple arrays is the best solution. If you don't know the quantity use arraylists, and finally if you require to use string indexes hashmaps are the solution. Using arrays would be the trivial solution.

Comment: Please make your answer complete.  You mention three different methods, so please format your answer accordingly.  _What are the advantages/disadvantages of each approach?_

Answer (score 2):

I can see three basic options here, considering you would work with `double` as an example:

1. Return array of `double` values

   - PRO: this is perhaps the easiest solution, quickly coded and with quite small memory usage since you work with primitive types here; if you need a new value, you just define array with one more element and add the new value to the end of the array
   - CON: you would have to "remember" what value is on which index and you would have to ensure these positions never change, otherwise callers of the method would start to have problems in the code that uses these returned values
2. Prepare your own class that hold all the values as its fields

   - PRO: this is probably the safest way, provided you either have all those values as zero (or other default value - in case of using primitives) or `null` (in case of using `Double`) to make adding new values in future releases safer (meaning it does not affect callers who started to use the class earlier); also, this is not limited to one data type only
   - CON: additional class to take care of - very simple one, so this is basically not a con :-)
3. Use `HashMap` of `Double` values

   - PRO: this may be somewhat easier to write/read - the more if you define your own class (enum?) for the map keys to ensure users only get supported values; `HashMap` is usually very fast
   - CON: somewhat more complicated as you would have more classes to manage; increased memory usage due to bigger amount of objects needed to achieve what you need; if you have only few values to return, this is probably unnecessarily complex

My personal choice would probably be to go with option 2 - use your own class and store the values in its fields, although it also depends on the usage scenario. In your case this could very likely be the way to go.

Comment: Option 2 would not have bigger memory usage, it would actually be smaller. An object with 4 int fields is the size of an object overhead + 4 int values, An array with 4 values is the size of an object overhead (the array object) + 4 int values + 1 int for the array length.

Comment: How about getters/setters, don't they need to be taken into account?

Comment: You're talking about the overhead of loading an additional class, I'm talking about the overhead of an object instance. You should never consider eliminating a class for size reasons, especially not if it removes clarity of the code. The memory usage of a single class or a single instance is meaningless, however the memory usage of 10000+ instances may make a difference.

Comment: OK, now I see your point. Thanks for bringing this up, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 ways to return multiple values from a method:

1. Return an array.
2. Return a collection, e.g. list or set.
3. Return an object with values.
4. Pass in a result collector.

Options 1 and 2 usually require all values to be same type, although that type can be a super class or interface. In the extreme case of using `Object`, any type can be used, but it eliminates the type safety of Java, so that's not a good idea.

Option 3 will require a custom class, but multiple values can have different names and types, providing more structure to heterogeneous values.

Option 4 can be use array (unlikely), collection, or custom class. Useful if multiple calls should keep adding to the same collector.

So, if all values are the same type, without different meaning, use option 1 or 2.
If values have different meaning, use option 3.
If repeated calls should append/merge with previous results, use option 4.

If values have same meaning, but different type, consider using an interface to unify the type.

---

In your case, you have 4 values of same type but different meaning, so option 3 would be best.

The `prompt()` method could then be a static method of that class, prompting the user and returning an instance of the class with the entered values. It should probably take the `BufferedReader` (or `Scanner`) as a parameter, in case the caller might want to prompt for other values too.

---

As an example to show this:

```
// Option 1 (return an array)
return new double[] { theta, omega, length, mass };

// Option 2 (return a collection)
List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(theta);
result.add(omega);
result.add(length);
result.add(mass);
return result;

// Option 3 (return an object)
// Not showing full implementation of Pendulum because it should be obvious)
return new Pendulum(theta, omega, length, mass);

// Option 4 (result collector)
void prompt(Pendulum result) {
    // existing code, then
    result.setTheta(theta);
    result.setOmega(omega);
    result.setLength(length);
    result.setMass(mass);
}
```